# emacs-snapshot - seq package missing

Tags: package

I use the following script to install Emacs 25 on Ubuntu, 

`sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ubuntu-elisp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install emacs-snapshot`

When I start the `emacs-snapshot` program I get this error message

`Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable seq)
  byte-code("\302\303\304\305#\210\302\303\306\307#\210\310\311!\2037
  require(seq)
  byte-code("\300\301!\210\300\302!\207" [require cl-lib seq] 2)
  require(cl-extra)`

It shows the `seq` package is missing, but I can't find it using the `package-list-packages` function.

How to fix this or is there another way to install Emacs 25 on Ubuntu?

Comment: This is likely related to the byte code in your config being incompatible. Try `emacs-snapshot -Q`.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong but I can use `emacs-snapshot -Q -l "~/.emacs"` to start Emacs, thanks you very much!!

Comment: I had a similar issue and deleted the .elc files in my .emacs.d and everything worked out.

Answer (score 8):

Looks like you've written

```
(require seq)
```

rather than

```
(require 'seq)
```