# How I can download the latest version of Emacs on Linux Mint 18.1?

Tags: linux, install

Linux Mint 18.1 (64 bit).

I install Emacs by Software Manager.

It download Emacs version 24.5. But the latest version is 25.1.

How I can download the latest version?

Comment: Well... 25.1 isn't exactly the latest version as of today. It would probably depend on what you mean by "latest". Do you mean the version packages for Linux Mint, or the one that was declared by Emacs developers as "latest", or, perhaps, the "latest stable" as declared by developers?

Comment: I mean this version. Here official site of Emacs. http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/  . You can see that latest version of Emacs = emacs-25.2.tar.gz

Comment: I see that Ubuntu 17 has Emacs 25 packaged here: https://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/emacs25 - you could try this one, but there's no telling whether you will have all the dependencies required available in your version of Mint. Else, you could just download one from the mirror.

Comment: Linux mint uses the same repositories as Ubuntu. Have a look at this question: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12772/prebuilt-ubuntu-emacs-25-1

Comment: Here article how install Emacs 25 on Linux Ubuntu http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/04/install-emacs-25-ppa-ubuntu-16-04-14-04/

Comment: Or use this: sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:adrozdoff/emacs;  
sudo apt update;  
sudo apt install emacs25